# A tripled riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Take the blackest of pits that yearns for the light

See the fruit that it has for distance and night

Now warp the fruit's name and turn up the bass

And what is the answer you pull from this chase?

Hints:

> The answer to the first line is a one inch wide bodypart in the head

> The answer to the second line is often used to make alcoholic beverages

> The third and fourth lines don't actually rhyme

> The answer has another name, like a tool

Comment: The first line could be cluing the rot13(chcvy).

Comment: And then the second line could be rot13(nccyr, nf vg'f nffbpvngrq jvgu chcvyf (fghqragf), naq vf hfrq gb znxr pvqre), but I don't see the connection to distance/night.

Comment: @LOTGP That's not quite right. I've edited the hints

Comment: Rot13(V tbg obgu fcrnesvfu naq crneysvfu, ohg V nffhzr gurl ner jebat nf gurl znxr ab frafr jungfbrire va pbagrkg.)

Comment: @Amoz How did you get those answers?

Comment: rot13(Ubj nobhg rlr -> tencr -> tncre?)

Comment: @LOTGP rot13(Lbh whfg arrq gur evtug qrsvavgvba sbe 'tncre')

Comment: rot13(uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Tncre_(svfu)? Orpnhfr n onff vf nyfb n svfu?)

Comment: @LOTGP rot13(Gung'f abg gur evtug svfu)

Comment: rot13(Jbhyq jvqrzbhgu onff jbex?  Bar pbhyq qrfpevor n jvqr zbhgu nf n "tncre" qhr gb orvat "ntncr".)

Comment: @LOTGP rot13(Gung'f abg gur evtug svfu rvgure. V'yy nqq n uvag)

Comment: @IchthysKing rot13(Gur bayl bgure tncre svfu frrzf gb or guvf: uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Erqrlr_tncre, ohg V qba'g frr ubj gung'f nal orggre.)

Comment: @LOTGP rot13(Gur pbeerpg svfu vf bsgra abg ersreerq gb nf n tncre)

Comment: Quite a lot of the answers here seem pretty valid, *especially* going off just the given riddle - and **if the hints are required** for a puzzle to be uniquely solvable, they're not hints any more, **they're integral parts of the puzzle.** If this wasn't bountied I'd be close-voting as inviting speculative answers by being ill-defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this might work?  Due to my attempts in the comments, I believe at least everything up to the third line is correct.

---

*Take the blackest of pits that yearns for the light*

> The **eye**, as the pupil is a black pit, and it is a small organ in the head.

*See the fruit that it has for distance and night*

> **Grape**, as per hexomino's mention of research about them being good for your eyes.

*Now warp the fruit's name and turn up the bass*

> Grape -> **Gaper**, as the mention of bass implies we need to get a fish.

*And what is the answer you pull from this chase?*

> A fish that is occasionally known as a gaper but also with a different, tool-related, name is the **comber**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comber_(fish)

Answer (score 4):

Long shot, but it kind of fits the riddle as given, so I'm giving it a try.

---

*Take the blackest of pits that yearns for the light*

> That sounds like HELL, the blackest pit in any mythology.

*See the fruit that it has for distance and night*

> In ancient Greek/Roman mythology, [Persephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persephone) is the queen of the underworld (hell), who was kidnapped by its king on condition that she would be released if she didn't eat any underworld food. She only ate a few pomegranate seeds, so for some months every year she's in the underworld and her mother (the goddess of agriculture) creates winter. Thus, POMEGRANATE is the fruit of hell, creating the seasons which could also be described more scientifically using distance (between the earth and the sun) and night (longer in winter, shorter in summer).

*Now warp the fruit's name and turn up the bass*

> Taking anagrams of POMEGRANATE, and removing the AMPERE which powers a bass, we get ...

*And what is the answer you pull from this chase?*

> ... remaining letters which could anagram to TANGO or TONGA.

Comment: This isn't quite right. I've added a hint

Comment: If a hint is required to invalidate a seemingly-valid answer, it's not really a hint any more - it's a vital part of the puzzle, required for making it uniquely solvable.

Answer (score 4):

Take the blackest of pits that yearns for the light

> Navel, belly button pit full of dirt and lint

See the fruit that it has for distance and night

> Navel Orange, distance=range, light=or=gold or orange light

Now warp the fruit's name and turn up the bass

> Nave Lo Range
> Lo Range=bass, turn it up might mean get rid of it?

And what is the answer you pull from this chase?

> Nave, the main part of a church, opposite of the blackest of pits, and definitely contains a trinity.

Comment: This isn't quite right. I've edited the hint

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding another answer because it is unrelated to my first guess. If that is inappropriate I will delete one.

---

*Take the blackest of pits that yearns for the light*

> The pupil of the eye is a black hole and its purpose is to admit light. This ties in with clues in the next line: "See", "distance" (vision), and "night" (vision).

*See the fruit that it has for distance and night*

> The [Longan fruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longan)'s name is Cantonese for "dragon eye" and it has a very black pit ("blackest of pits"). Perhaps the fruit helps with distance and night vision?

*Now warp the fruit's name and turn up the bass*

> If "warping" means rearranging letters and "turn up the bass" means going from "lo" to "hi" then we can get...

*And what is the answer you pull from this chase?*

> lo hangin fruit

Comment: This isn't quite right. I've added a hint

Comment: Parts 1 and 2 sounds spot on to me, though we'll have to see what the OP intends. I'm not convinced about your interpretation of bass (and why is it bass instead of base? Is it because he's the Ichthys King, and therefore it's a fish reference?)

Answer (score 2):

Here goes nothing...

> eye -- line 2 mentions it "sees"

> grape

> grouper -- grape with mangled letters and some fishiness (bass) added.

> rope -- a tool often used for pulling, the letters are also in "grouper" so you can 'pull' it out.

Comment: This isn't quite right

Answer (score 1):

take the blackest of pits that yearns for the light

> the eye

See the fruit that it has for distance and night

> Apple, as in 'the apple of my eye'. This phrase can be found in Shakespeare's a midsummer *night's* dream. As for distance, the average apple is equivalent to roughly one newton, which can be measured with a newton *meter*

Now warp the fruits name and turn up the bass

> Add the word bass to the word apple and scramble it

And what is the answer you pull from this chase

> The longest anagram we get from this is the word *passable*, which is ironic because this answer is a bit of a stretch

Comment: This isn't quite right. I've added a hint

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer might be

> Bagger

Take the blackest of pits that yearns for the light

> I think this is **eye** as suggested by other answers and the first hint (the black pit being the pupil)

See the fruit that it has for distance and night

> Looking at the second hint I think this must be **grape** (recent research has suggested that grapes help keep your eyes healthy).

Now warp the fruit's name and turn up the bass

> A possible anagram of grape is **pager**.
>  Turning up the bass could be suggesting wordplay involving literally turning the first letter up (i.e, 'p' becomes 'b') to get **bager**.

And what is the answer you pull from this chase?

> There's an extra **g** I'm putting in here which I cannot explain other than to say **bager** sort of looks like **bagger** but there are other reasons why this might work.
>  For example, in baseball, a double bagger is a hit which allows the batter to immediately run to second base, so we get the idea of chasing the bases and the link with the word 'bass' in the previous line.

Title

> A triple bagger, in baseball, is a hit which allows the batter to run to third base.

Other links

> The batter's **eye** is a solid-coloured area beyond the center field wall of a baseball stadium, that is the visual backdrop directly in the line of sight of a baseball batter, while facing the pitcher and awaiting a pitch

Comment: This isn't quite right. I've added a hint